# What is the name of the basis that uses objects of definite parity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, terminology

Currents to which gauge fields couple in four dimensions can be described as follows:

$$
\mathcal{L} = -g A_\mu J^\mu.
$$

Sometimes it useful to discuss these couplings in the *chiral* basis, $J_\text{L}^\mu$ and $J_\text{R}^\mu$ (*i.e.* left and right chiral currents), where under spacetime parity, the two currents transform into each other.

Other times, it is useful to describe them using objects of definite parity, $J_\text{V}^\mu$ and $J_\text{A}^\mu$ (*i.e.* vector and axial-vector currents).   What is the name of *this* basis most commonly used in the literature?  Is there a one-word terminology for it?